# Cypress, Vite - Load a file in a way which works in prod, Component Testing, and Test Scripts

Tags: typescript, cypress, vite

I have a script which loads some YAML data and exports it, for example:

```js
// foo.ts
export const data = {}
fetch("/data.yaml").then((response) => {
    // ^ stored in Vite's public directory, which means that it gets put at the webroot in prod
    response.text().then((text) => {
        const tmp = parse(text);
        Object.assign(data, tmp);
    })
})
```

This works fine in prod. But it doesn't work in cypress component testing or when imported from a Cypress script.

**What is the """Correct""" way to load a file which works in prod, Cypress Component Testing, *and* Cypress Test Scripts?**

Comment: Seems a bit obvious, so probably a wrinkle there - why not copy it into `cypress/fixtures`?

Comment: Or just use `cy.readFile()` from the `src` location?

Comment: Can't you `import` the yaml file?

Comment: @Udo.Kier I want to use all the same code because in my actual app it's not just `Object.assign`; it does other stuff.

Comment: @Kokodoko if it's possible I don't know how

Comment: When you say "load a file" - do you want the test to load the contents of `data.yaml` independent of the app, or is it just that `foo.ts` breaks when you run through Cypress?

Comment: @SSpall I need it to load data.yaml independent of the app.

Comment: It needs to work in component testing so that the components can display it, and it needs to work in the test scripts so that i can compare it to what the components are displaying